# How to route ALL requests for domain to a sub folder asp.net

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I have seen lots of solutions to this but none seem to work....

I have a domain

```
producerpte.co.uk
```

But I have a separate application set up in a sub folder so to see the root of that application you have to go to...

```
producerpte.co.uk/producerpte
```

However I want it so that the user does not see the 'site1' part of the url.

When I use url rewriting in `Web.Server` config or I use `Context.RewritePath` in code (in an application set up on the root) it simply redirects the user to the url (with site1 in it) I do not want the user to know they are going to a subfolder.

Am I setting this up wrong?

I'm actually using Winhost. All the examples ive tried just do not change result of the call without redirecting the url :-(

I have been told by winhost that I should do it with code/configuration. I would prefer to do it with code to be honest....

UPDATE : I tried Max's answer and I did...

```
 <rules>
    <rule name="Redirect if producerpte" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="^ producerpte/(.*)$" />
        <action type="Redirect" url="{R:1}" />
    </rule>
    <rule name="Rewrite to sub folder">
        <match url="^.*$" />
        <action type="Rewrite" url="producerpte/{R:0}" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
```

But no luck :-( And the urls still change in the browser....

Comment: Do winhost run IIS 7 or above? Did they install IIS Rewrite Module?

Comment: IIS 8 but they say I need to do it with code!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If WinHost did enable IIS Rewrite Module, edit your `web.config` file and give this rule a try:

```
<rewrite>
<rules>
    <rule name="Redirect if site1" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="^site1/(.*)$" />
        <action type="Redirect" url="{R:1}" />
    </rule>
    <rule name="Rewrite to sub folder">
        <match url="^.*$" />
        <action type="Rewrite" url="site1/{R:0}" />
    </rule>
</rules>
</rewrite>
```

**--- UPDATE ---**

Well, I tested this IIS configuration:

[image]

I've added rules on the **root** site.
IIS created a `web.config` file:

[image]

Here's the content of the web.config file:

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
             <rules>
                <rule name="Redirect if producerpte" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^producerpte/(.*)$" />
                    <action type="Redirect" url="{R:1}" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="Rewrite to sub folder">
                    <match url="^.*$" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="producerpte/{R:0}" />
                </rule>
              </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

- `http://localhost:8066/` displays the content of `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\producerpte\producerpte` without changing the URL in browser
- `http://localhost:8066/producerpte/` displays the content of `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\producerpte\producerpte` but the URL in browser is changed to `http://localhost:8066/`

Be sure that you created rules on the **root** site (and not the sub application) and I noticed that you had a leading space in your config: `<match url="^ producerpte/(.*)$" />` between `^` and `producerpte`.

Comment: Hi Max, actually the full root is...

producerpte.co.uk/producerpte/ - this works out of the box however when I put the config...

<rules>
    <rule name="Redirect if producerpte" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="^ producerpte/(.*)$" />
        <action type="Redirect" url="{R:1}" />
    </rule>
    <rule name="Rewrite to sub folder">
        <match url="^.*$" />
        <action type="Rewrite" url="producerpte/{R:0}" />
    </rule>
  </rules>

I get a 404, its trying to go to producerpte/producerpte (and the urls are changing too - i really dont want this :-()

Comment: Okay I played around a bit now its just redirecting but I want it to return the content but not change the url is this even possible?

Comment: Hi Max, yep this basically was the right answer so I have marked it so. However now im struggling to work out how to do multiple folders can you believe it cant believe how hard this is....im trying to modify your second rule to pick up the domain name producerpte.co.uk only so that I can do my girlfriends site in a similar fasion samyoga...dont suppose you know how? Sorry youve been enough help already if not thankyou...but ive been trying for days on this literally! thanks pete