# Admin App with the landing page, routing

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, routes

So far when I open root location, it is an admin home page (i.e. www.example.com), and i would like to make an landing page in that root location, but all admin things i would like to have in separate folder (i.e. www.example.com/admin/).

In example routing option for 'uses' currently is www.example.com/uses/ and I would like to have it in www.exaple.com/admin/users, but I dont want to change the project structure only routing. How can i make it with the minimal change?

EDIT:
I have tried registering routes in *MvcApplication* class in *Global.asax.cs*, but it didn't work

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes){
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default",                                              
            "admin/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" }
        );
}
```

But this didn't work out.

Answer (score 0):

For Asp, I would reference the following exert from Microsoft:

**Routes**

A route is a URL pattern that is mapped to a handler. The handler can be a physical file, such as an .aspx file in a Web Forms application. A handler can also be a class that processes the request, such as a controller in an MVC application. To define a route, you create an instance of the [Route](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.routing.route.aspx) class by specifying the URL pattern, the handler, and optionally a name for the route.

You add the route to the application by adding the [Route](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.routing.route.aspx) object to the static [Routes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.routing.routetable.routes.aspx) property of the [RouteTable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.routing.routetable.aspx) class. The [Routes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.routing.routetable.routes.aspx) property is a [RouteCollection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.routing.routecollection.aspx) object that stores all the routes for the application.

You typically do not have to write code to add routes in an MVC application. Visual Studio project templates for MVC include preconfigured URL routes. These are defined in the MvcApplication class, which is defined in the Global.asax file.

Src. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

*What I would do is create an **ADMIN** controller, and then set up routes something like so: {controller}/{page}/{action}*

Alternatively, you can follow this solution to rewrite routes to subfolder: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17074898/2267583

Comment: Thank you for the help. In EDIT i have put the thing i have tried but still haven't worked.
Can you please provide some example about the _{controller}/{page}/{action}_ controller structure. I am only familiar with the _{controller}/{action}_ structure, or _{controller}/{action}/{parameter}_

Comment: have you tried the second example of just rewriting routes to subfolder?
What are the errors you are having? and have you tried naming your **controller** *Admin* ?